# jQuery Effects on Ajax Refresh

Tags: jquery, ajax, css

I am using jQuery to implement Ajax in my project. Is it possible to use effects on an html element on every Ajax refresh? For example, `fadein()` on a div every Ajax refresh. Also, if possible can I use a CSS3 effect like box-shadow with a transition:

```
box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 255, 1);
transition: all 0.10s ease-in-out;
```

By Ajax refresh I mean everytime Ajax is used to refresh something on a page. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, just put the relevant fx/animation code in the `success` callback in your jQuery AJAX call.

If you want to use CSS3 rather than jQuery animations, write classes for each state, add transitions and use `.addClass` and `.removeClass` (or `.toggleClass`) to trigger the animation (this would also go in the success callback).

Answer (score 0):

Sure, you can either fire the fadein() on the success callback of the $.ajax (or $.post or whichever flavor you're using) or you can bind it via the .on method (http://api.jquery.com/on/)